# PostgreSQL returns java.sql.Types.OTHER when i select a constant with AS keyword

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

When run the select on Postgres over java

```
SELECT '' AS COL1, 0 AS COL2 FROM MYTABLE 1=2;
```

Column type is `Types.OTHER` both for COL1 and COL2. As it is obvious resultset has not any row.

But if I have rows in result set using the query below:

```
SELECT '' AS COL1, 0 AS COL2 FROM MYTABLE;
```

Type of COL1 is still `Types.OTHER` but COL2 type is `Types.INTEGER`. In my case I need `Types.VARCHAR` and `Types.INTEGER` even result is empty or not.

Are there any configurations on db layer or jdbc url to get `Types.VARCHAR` and `Types.INTEGER` both for two queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Postgres JDBC driver 9.4.1212 reports the type of constant 0 as `Types.INTEGER` = 4, regardless if there is a result or not (this may also depend on the Server version - I tested with a 9.4 server).

The string constant is still reported as `Types.OTHER`. For such columns `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnClassName(i)` returns `java.lang.String`, so if you encounter a `Types.OTHER` you can use this information to recognize the column as a character column.

If you want the `ResultSetMetaData` to return the wanted type, grab the sources from Github and patch the `ResultSetMetaData` to do this translation.

Comment: but ... in PostgreSQL the `'xyz'` literal is *not* a string, neither a varchar, or text. It is `unknown`. The JDBC driver kind of correct here, to report it as `Types.OTHER`. (Note: [this is supposed to be changed](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=1e7c4bb0049732ece651d993d03bb6772e5d281a) in a future release).

Comment: @pozs yep, I expected that postgres has a rationale for its return value. Another argument that the OP should do some postprocessing of the metadata and not expect that his problem can be solved by tweaking the database.

Answer (score 3):

try explicit cast:

```
SELECT ''::VARCHAR  AS COL1, 0::INTEGER AS COL2 FROM MYTABLE;
```

Comment: My application works on different database systems. As first option i need something like a configuration to avoid too much workload. Because i have too many similar queries and it is not easy implement a kind of adapter due to database that i connect.

Comment: @bahtiyartan you can also use the ANSI standard cast syntax: `CAST('' AS VARCHAR)` -- but I have to say that I see no real use-case behind your query (i.e. supply a constant value to be returned). If you explain your *actual* problem, we may be able to come up with a better solution.